# Search and Push n elements into custom_arr from x_arr where condition with y_arr

Tags: python, numpy, adaboost

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, I don't know how else can I make this question more specific.

I am trying to create an Adaboost implementation in Python, I am using the MNIST from Keras datasets.

Currently, I am just trying to create a training array for a weak threshold that classifies the "0" number images.

For that, I need to create an array, half of it being just images of "0", and the other half being any other random number.

Currently, I have 2 arrays, `x_train`: an array that contains the pictures and `y_train`: an array that contains the tag, that way we can check if, for example, `x_train[i]` is a picture of the number "0" if `y_train[i] == 0`.

[image]

So, I want to know if there's an automated way of doing that using NumPy, to grab elements from an array using a condition applied to another array.

Basically: Grab n elements and push into custom_array from x_array[i] if y_array[i] == 0 , and, grab n elements and push into custom_array from x_array[i] if y_array[i] != 0.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this serve your purpose?

```py
mask = y_array == 0

array_0 = x_array[mask]
array_non0 = x_array[~mask]
```

If I interpreted your question the wrong way, please correct me.